# How to display a text/movieclip for some seconds and remove an object in Action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am beginner programmer in flash (actionscript3) , and I want to make a short Point And Click style game,

I have a room with a Door which needed key to open and a Box which contains Key for the Door.
I made it right you can watch SWF file(the link down my question). but I have 2 problems :

1- when I click on Box , I see inside the box and when I pick up the key , and return to the 
room , and again I click on Box , I see the key again , but I don't want this happen , what should I do ? remove it ? how ?

2- when I click on Door , text "key needed" appears , but I want to disappear it after 3 seconds for example. How can I do this ?

If I should put my codes , just tell me and I will put them here.

this is what I made : http://apple-pib.persiangig.com/Point_And_Click.swf

this is my code about the Key :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

key.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK , keypickedup ) ;

function keypickedup (event : MouseEvent ) : void {   
canyouopendoor =true;
key.visible = false;


}
```

and my code about Door :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop ();
keyneeded.visible = false;

door.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK , thedoor ) ;

function thedoor (event : MouseEvent ) : void {
if (canyouopendoor ==true) {
gotoAndStop (4);
}

else {
keyneeded.visible = true ;

}

 }
```

Best Regards'

Comment: It really depends on how you made your game. But I think you need to remove the key with `removeChild` or something. And for the other you need to use a `setTimeout` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I put the codes in my post.if you don't mind , take a look at them.

Comment: thanks I fixed one of my problem with ( setTimeout )

Comment: So you have multiple frames? One for the door and one for the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like your variable `canyouopendoor` you need to have a variable that is `true` if you picked up your key or `false` when you havent. But you could also use `canyouopendoor` since that is only true when you have picked up the key.

You need to add this line to your code for the key:

```
key.visible = !canyouopendoor;
```

And you need to use `setTimeout` to wait a few seconds before you hide your text above the door. Something like:

```
setTimeout(function():void { keyneeded.visible = false; }, 3000);
```

`3000` for 3 seconds.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you again, I fixed timeout problem , but still have problem with the key , if you have time please take a look out my source file : [link] (http://apple-pib.persiangig.com/Point_And_Click.fla) when I click on Key , it will disappear , and but again when I click on Box it will appear.

Comment: I think my problem occur because of using multiple frames

Comment: I think the problem is that your variable gets reset. You could change your file to have all the variables in the first frame and let your game start at frame 2 so when you come back to the frame where the door is in, the variables won't be overridden. If that makes sense.

Comment: what should I do exactly ? have you seen the FLA file ?

Comment: I cant view your file but I suggest moving your 'door' frame to frame 2 and your 'key' frame to frame 3. (Or at least have frame 1 empty). Place your variable `canyouopendoor` in frame 1, but don't add the `stop();` command to frame 1.

Comment: I fixed it with this code on "key" frame on main timeline :

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);
 
    function myFunction(event:Event):void
    {
    if (canyouopendoor ==false) {
 key.visible = true;
 }
 else {
  key.visible = false;
  
 }
    }


and it works fine but in output window , it gave me en error :

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Point_And_Click_fla::MainTimeline/myFunction()[Point_And_Click_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:48]

Comment: You get that error because you are assigning an event listener to the stage on frame 4. When you go back to frame 2 the event listener is still there but your key is not. It is searching for that key that is not there. So either remove the listener or check the key without the listener.

Comment: how can I check the key without listener , what command except Enterframe can do that ?